# вывод значения в LOG из массива Event

Tags: javascript

Уточните как в JS вывести в лог не весь массив от события а определенную переменную:

```
MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 553, screenY: 357, clientX: 553, clientY: 291, …}
```

выводится в результате:

```
console.log(e)
```

Как написать строчку чтоб вывести только `screenX`
или по другому, как получить в свою переменную значение `screenX`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так в консоль:

```
console.log(e.screenX);
```

Или в переменную:

```
var x = e.screenX
```

Comment: спасибо,   моя ошибка -> console.log(e.MouseEvent.clientX), просто выглядит логичнее, но не работает)

Comment: @RustemI дело в том, что `e` - это и есть `MouseEvent`. Если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как правильный.